# Add and remove functions in javascript array (React-Hooks)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a filtering system where I use an array to add or remove the filtering methods. But my state is not working properly or i've missed something.

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);
const [creatorFilter, setCreatorFilter] = useState(null);

const handleCreatorFilter =(filter) => {
        setCreatorFilter(filter);

        if (filter === 'structures' && filters.indexOf(byStructureFilter) === -1) {
            setFilters([...filters, byStructureFilter]);
        }

        if (filter === 'members' && filters.indexOf(byMemberFilter) === -1) {
            setFilters([...filters, byMemberFilter]);
        }

        if (filter === 'all') {
            setFilters(filters.filter(el => el !== byStructureFilter || el !== byMemberFilter));
        }
    };

    const byStructureFilter = (item) => {
        return item.relationships.structure.data
    };

    const byMemberFilter = (item) => {
        return item.relationships.user.data && !item.relationships.structure.data
    };
```

Here the two buttons calling that `handleCreatorFilter` for filtering

```
<button onClick={() => creatorFilter === 'structures' ? handleCreatorFilter('all') : handleCreatorFilter('structures')}>Structures officielles</button>
<button onClick={() => creatorFilter === 'members' ? handleCreatorFilter('all') : handleCreatorFilter('members')} >Membres Wekomkom</button>
```

The things is for adding filtering methods to the array it works fine but not when the filter is set to `all` (removing the filtering methods). Do you see something wrong in my logic ?